# Global Shortcut not working 15.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

I have a keyboard with media shorts and they work to pause music playing in chrome globally.

**My Global Settings:**

[image: My Global Settings]

**My Chrome Shortcut keys:**

[image: My Chrome Shortcut keys]

However when I hit Cntrl+Alt+Z the audio won't pause.

Why don't they :(